# Intuit PARTY name must be unique error during UPDATE with NO name changes

Tags: rest, intuit-partner-platform

Ran into this error when Updating a customer without changing name.  Have not seen any explanation at all so far.  Party Reference Id could be the problem?  The name was ok, since the record already created, just posting an update. Anyone has ideas?

Request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Mod Draft="false" FullResponse="true" RequestId="2b32f09b926d47209aceffdc3d20eb9f" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/junk" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns3="http://platform.intuit.com/api/v1">
  <Customer>
    <Id idDomain="QB">11</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
      <CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy>
      <CreateTime>2013-04-10T16:28:19Z</CreateTime>
      <LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-10T17:57:50Z</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <ExternalKey idDomain="QB">11</ExternalKey>
    <Synchronized>true</Synchronized>
    <PartyReferenceId idDomain="QB">11</PartyReferenceId>
    <TypeOf>Organization</TypeOf>
    <Name>Demo 001</Name>
    <Address>
      <Line1>123 Street</Line1>
      <Line2>Demo Bond</Line2>
      <City>San Francisco</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>94108</PostalCode>
      <Tag>Billing</Tag>
    </Address>
    <Phone>
      <Id idDomain="QB">00000000000001Vj</Id>
      <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
      <FreeFormNumber>222-222-2222</FreeFormNumber>
      <Default>true</Default>
      <Tag>Business</Tag>
    </Phone>
    <Email>
      <Address>demo@test.test</Address>
      <Default>true</Default>
      <Tag>Business</Tag>
    </Email>
    <GivenName>Demo</GivenName>
    <FamilyName>Bond</FamilyName>
    <DBAName>Demo 001</DBAName>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <ShowAs>Demo 001</ShowAs>
    <SalesTermId idDomain="QB">6</SalesTermId>
    <SalesTermName>Net 30</SalesTermName>
    <OpenBalance>
      <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
      <Amount>43</Amount>
    </OpenBalance>
    <OpenBalanceDate>2013-04-10</OpenBalanceDate>
    <JobInfo>
      <Status>None</Status>
    </JobInfo>
  </Customer>
</Mod>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 17:24:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Response-Routing-Time: 564
Content-Length: 367
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
<Error RequestId="2b32f09b926d47209aceffdc3d20eb9f">
    <RequestName>ErrorRequest</RequestName>
    <ProcessedTime>2013-04-24T17:24:49.092Z</ProcessedTime>
    <ErrorCode>-3002</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDesc>PARTY name must be unique ERI=629577300</ErrorDesc>
    <DBErrorCode>20377</DBErrorCode>
</Error>
</RestResponse>
```

Comment: Do you know what URL you're POSTing data to?

Comment: Did you ever find out the issue here?  I'm running across the same scenario.  Performing a MOD - not ADD - on a customer that already exists in QuickBooks.  I'm just trying to change his telephone number.

Comment: Here's my full request/response in case Intuit or anyone else has an idea.  http://pastebin.com/Xwdz8vbU

Answer (score 1):

The error means there is already a customer, vendor or employee with the same name as the customer you are trying to add in the above request.

Query for an existing record with that first + last combo

regards,
Jarred

Answer (score 0):

Our team found this issue when issuing an AddVendor request containing a Vendor Name that existed but the name in our Request contained a trailing space.  It appears that Quickbooks is stripping the trailing space.  Stripping the trailing space resolved the issue.